# is there a typescript reference for office.js?

Tags: typescript, office-js

Does anyone know of a TypeScript reference or declarations file for Office 2013 task pane apps?

I tried adding:

```
/// <reference path="_officeintellisense.js" />
/// <reference path="office/1.0/office.js" />
```

But tsc can't seem to interpret office.js (or at least I can't get it to) because it seems to be context-aware, needing to know if it is running in Excel, Word, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a .d.ts file with type information to get auto-completion and type checking.

You can declare just the bits you need to use, and you can just treat it as dynamic at first before adding more detailed type information. For example if the script exposes an Office object, you could start with:

```
declare var Office: any;
```

Comment: ah, the 'declare' statement - I was just using var (which seems to work the same).  I added "declare var Office: any;"  No intellisense, but that's fine - I just need it to compile. Thx much.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the Office Extensibility team at Microsoft just released the Office.js TypeScript definitions as well, including the [newly added APIs for Excel & Word 2016](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs). You can find it on the [DefinitelyTyped github repository](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/office-js/index.d.ts) or on [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/office-js.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/).

~ Michael Zlatkovsky

Developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT